# How to dynamically add elements to the array value of an SplObjectStorage object

Tags: php, oop

Suppose we have an **Index** *class*:

```
class Index{
    /* indexing fields */
    public $id ;
    public $word;
    
    /* Constructor */
    public function __construct($id, $word)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->word = $word;
    }
}
```

So far so good? ok.

Now, imagine we have to implement a dictionary that maps words to their synonyms.

```
/* Create SplObjectStorage object. should work as data-structure that 
     resembles a HashMap or Dictionary */
     $synonymsDictionary = new \SplObjectStorage(); 

/* Create a word index object, and add it to synonyms dictionary */
    $word = new Index(1,"bad");
    $synonymsDictionary[$word] = array("evil", "mean", "php");

/* print it out */
    echo var_dump($synonymsDictionary[$word]);
```

This outputs:

```
array(3) {
 [0]=>
   string(4) "evil"
 [1]=>
   string(4) "mean"
 [2]=>
   string(3) "php"
 }
```

If wanna **add one more synonym to our word**, how to go about that? I tried this:

```
/* Adding one more synonym */
   $synonymsDictionary->offsetGet($word)[] = "unlucky"; 
   echo var_dump($synonymsDictionary[$word]);
```

This, however, outputs the same output as the one above :

```
     array(3) {
        [0]=>
   string(4) "evil"
        [1]=>
   string(4) "mean"
        [2]=>
   string(3) "php"
 }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save all synonyms as array instead of single string:

```
$synonymsDictionary[$word] = array("evil", "mean", "php");
```

So now you can add new item `$synonymsDictionary[$word][] = 'unlucky'`

---

Also `offsetGet` only returns data, not reference to data. So what you later change is never assigned back to synonyms dictionary.

So you need this:

```
$data = $sd->offsetGet($word);
$data[] = 'unlucky';
$sd->offsetSet($word, $data);
```

Comment: Still the problem is there, that was a typo. I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Have a look again at the question.

Comment: Works, cool trick. Can we somehow get a reference to the array? the overhead of returning a copy of the array, instead of a reference, is unreasonable to me. 

Comment: @Elg Extend SplObjectStorage with your own class and overwrite this function